# Change Comma to dot for all my inserts

Tags: c#, sql

I'm using this code for insert from Excel to SQL. I want every insert in my query to have comma replaced by dot.

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into Market (Barcode,Name,Code,TemporaryStock,VatcodeID,Unit,NetValue,DiscountValue,UnderlyingValue,VatValue,TotalValue) 
select * from OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=" + textBox1.Text + "', 'SELECT * FROM [datasheet1$H:R]')", con);

cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Should I use global System.Globalization.CultureInfo?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Which comma do you mean? Something in the resultset of the other query?

Comment: You can use `REPLACE()` function of SQL Server for each field ;).

Comment: No, that would most likely be part of the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` settings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027552/reading-excel-files-in-a-locale-independent-way

Answer (score -1):

For replacing chars/strings in another string use the `string.Replace` method.

```
string str = "insert into Market(Barcode,Name,Code,TemporaryStock,VatcodeID,Unit,NetValue,DiscountValue,UnderlyingValue,VatValue,TotalValue) select * from OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=" + textBox1.Text + "', 'SELECT * FROM [datasheet1$H:R]')";

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(str.Replace(',', '.'), con);
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You can find detailed info about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Works fine for me.. You could try using str.Replace(",", ".") to replace them as strings.

Comment: Should I use replace i